# Why Can't GrUB Find a Kernel That It Already Found?

Tags: boot, kernel, 15.04, grub-legacy

After upgrading to 15.04, I need to have kernel headers matching the running kernel (for another package).

The upgrade installed kernel 3.19.0-17.  Just in case, I also installed `linux-headers-generic`.  Then, I ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted.  Yet, the system booted into kernel 3.16.0-31 (as confirmed by `uname -r`).

After much digging, I found that GrUB recognizes the 3.19 kernel in `update-grub` and even populates it into `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.  However, on startup, GrUB *only recognizes up to the 3.16 kernel in the boot menu*.  **How do I fix this, so that GrUB can boot into 3.19?**

---

Here are some outputs from my current system.

`sudo update-grub` always produces the following output:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-17-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-31-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-17-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-31-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

Opening `/boot/grub/menu.lst` after running `update-grub`, the very first option is:

```
title        Ubuntu 15.04, kernel 3.19.0-17-generic
uuid        ac9d0eaf-e090-4c29-8e7b-30e98ed07d29
kernel        /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-17-generic root=UUID=ac9d0eaf-e090-4c29-8e7b-30e98ed07d29 ro quiet splash
initrd        /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-17-generic
```

But, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot, there is no option to choose 3.19 (although I can choose any of the others).  After startup, `uname -r` confirms it booted into 3.16:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-31-generic
```

Output cropped from a `dpkg -l`, showing that the 3.19 kernel is indeed installed:

```
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-17                              3.19.0-17.17                               all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-17-generic                      3.19.0-17.17                               amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                3.19.0.17.16                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

---

I have also tried purge/reinstalling grub and the headers, and some other things that amounted to no consequence.

Comment: For grub, the `linux-image-*` packages are more important than the `linux-headers-*` packages.

Comment: On my system, I don't have a `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, but instead have a `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, which seems to get updated instead. The man page for `update-grub` suggests that it calls `grub-mkconfig`, telling it to output the data to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Do you have a file named `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and does it not have the newer kernel?

Comment: @saiarcot895 `linux-image-3.19.0-17-generic` is also present in the `dpkg` listing. I do have a `grub.cfg` file, and it indeed lacks the 3.19 record.

Comment: Try removing (make sure you have a back-up) `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and `/boot/grub/default` (if the latter exists) and run `update-grub` again. Check to see if `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` now contains the 3.19 record.

Comment: @saiarcot895 [done](http://pastebin.com/iLCheYCn). It does not.

Comment: Can you verify that you have `grub2-common` installed? (Run `sudo apt-get install grub2-common` if you're not sure.)

Comment: @saiarcot895 I do not have it installed. As tagged above, the GrUB version is 0.97. Do you think should upgrade to GrUB 2?

Comment: Yes. That's probably why you're having that problem.

Comment: @saiarcot895 after installing GrUB 2, redoing your (n-2)nd comment, and then rebooting, it boots into 3.19. If you repost the above and also explain what 0.97's problem was, that sounds like an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The older version of GRUB (0.9.7) likely used `menu.lst` to determine what to display, while the newer version of GRUB (GRUB 2) uses `grub.cfg` instead. It looks like you have some mix of GRUB and GRUB 2 installed.

Using `update-grub` from the `grub` package will update the `menu.lst` file, which will effectively do nothing if the bootloader is GRUB 2, which is what is happening here. Instead, you should install `grub2-common` (which should uninstall the `grub` package). Then, when running `update-grub` (or `update-grub2`; both do the same thing), the `grub.cfg` file gets updated instead.

Answer based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63076/default-kernel-is-missing-from-grub-1-menu?rq=1) answer.